# My entities are deleted when the app is exported

Tags: chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I've created an app in LUIS and added a number of custom entities (type simple and list). I noticed that when I export the app to a json file some of the tags I added in the LUIS interface are missing. Is this a known issue? Are there any workarounds? Thanks!

EDITED: I added the following screenshots. Although it is in Spanish I think it's clear that the entity tags in the online interface do not show up in the downloaded json file.
[Downloaded json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH66Q.png)
[View from online interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD4cF.png)

Steps taken:
-added entities (type closed list in this example)
-added intent and utterances
-tagged utterances with entities
-train
-download json

I haven't checked whether the missing entities are always closed lists, but this is the case in this example

Comment: Do you confirm that at the time of export you had at least one example of each custom entity in at least one sample utternace? Or did you just create the entity that was not marked yet in any sample utterance?

Comment: Yes, the entities are being used in the utterances. Some of the utterances that have entity labels in the interface do not have these labels in the exported json. I haven't detected any pattern, it looks that some entity labels get deleted randomly...

Comment: If you see labeled List Entities in your Utterances in the UI then none of them are exported with startPos and endPos. Only the whole list is in closedLists. After you import such luisApp version you don't see the List Entities labeles until you do the first Train. Unlike with the Simple Entities that are visible after import without the need to perform Train.

Comment: Could you eventually append detailed steps to reproduce? And perhaps your LUIS app exported for download?

Comment: @LaraG My name is Ashley. If you'd like, you can add my Microsoft account as a collaborator to your LUIS app (asho@microsoft.com), and I can see directly a repro of the issue. Additionally, let me know, which tags are missing exactly, that way I can compare my own results with what you're reporting

Comment: oops, i mean v-asho@microsoft.com *

Comment: @Zeryth and Ferdinand Fejskid sorry, I can't do that, I added a couple of screenshots and steps though. I'll try to create another app were I can repro the issue and add you or share it